# Expand and simplify an expression based on a string input

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, math, sympy

I have an input like `"2(5x+4) + 3(2x-1)"` in plain text and I need to expand and simplify it. It appears `sympy` requires it to be entered as a python object made up of python types. Is there a way to automatically parse it / a library that doesn't require it so I can give it the string and it gives me the answer in a human readable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sympy already has such a parser built-in under `sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr`. To get the results you want with your input statement you also have to add the `implicit_multiplication` transformation (since sympy otherwise won't generate statements that make sense for `2(` and `5x`):

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (
    parse_expr,
    standard_transformations, 
    implicit_multiplication,
)
parse_expr("2(5x+4) + 3(2x-1)", transformations=standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication,))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [sympify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html) function, for your expression it's gonna be like this:

```
sympify('2*(5*x+4) + 3*(2*x-1)')
```